# Is it possible to configure socket connection(not web) in Nginx reverse proxy server

Tags: sockets, go, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a CLI client and server written in Go Currently, they are communicating via a socket connection and it's a server streaming connection Now I want to have an Nginx proxy between these two

Is it possible to configure the normal socket connection in Nginx? How do that, and what all code changes & configuration changes I need to do

There's not much on the internet on this on socket connection in Nginx I was wondering if it's possible or not

```
//my client code:
func getStreammessages() {
    connection, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8888")
    _, err = connection.Write([]byte(sendIDtoServertoGetStream))
    for {
        mLen, err := connection.Read(buffer)
        //some logic to print the message stream
    }
}

//my server code:
func StartStreamServer() {
    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.2:9988")
    defer server.Close()
    for {
        connection, err := server.Accept()
        go registerClient(connection)
    }
}
func registerClient(connection net.Conn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
    mLen, err := connection.Read(buffer)
    var sendIDtoServertoGetStream message
    err = json.Unmarshal(buffer[:mLen], &sendIDtoServertoGetStream)
}

//strem to client from message queue
func StreamMessageToCliCLient(connection net.Conn) {
    _, err = connection.Write(messageString)
}
```

Have anyone done this before

currently, I am doing this in my Nginx (nginx.conf file) which is running in the same VM as my server

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
            default upgrade;
            '' close;
    }
    upstream wsbackend {
          server 127.0.0.2:9988;
    }
    server {
          listen 8888; 
          location /{
                auth_basic  off;
                proxy_ssl off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass wsbackend;
          }
          location /v1/config {
                proxy_pass http://$CONFIG_MGMT_HOST:$CONFIG_MGMT_PORT/v1/config;
          } 
    } 
}
```

I want to open Port 8888
Internally proxy pass to my server, with this setup, currently getting 400 error in log, Can you pls help Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `proxy_pass wsbackend;` with `proxy_pass http://wsbackend;`